# Stack notification in parse

Tags: parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, parse-android-sdk

How can I do stack notifications in parse android?
I send the push messages for the device, example:

```
ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
 androidPush.setMessage("TEST");
 androidPush.sendInBackground();
```

For example , if I send two notifications then appear two icons in phone bar. I want to have only 1 icon.

Comment: What do you mean stack Ron? Increment?

Comment: I mean to when I send 2 push for example, in the phone bar appear 2 icon notifications, right? I want only 1 icon of all messages sent.

Answer (score 0):

have you try with following way ?

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"The Mets scored!\",
                                   \"badge\": \"Increment\",
                                   \"sound\": \"cheering.caf\"}");
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("Mets");
push.setData(data);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

with about code you need to set same object for multiple notifications.

Comment: Increment doesn't work in Android. You need to handle it on the client side using a custom Receiver class. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this out myself :(